# The Service "php" is invalid: spec.ports: Required value

Tags: php, service, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine

I was following this tutorial https://www.cloudbooklet.com/kubernetes-basic-php-application-with-nginx-on-google-cloud/ and when I got to this command `kubectl apply -f php_service.yaml --validate=false` this error popped up:

> The Service "php" is invalid: spec.ports: Required value.

How do I fix this? This is the yaml file:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: php
      labels:
        tier: backend
    spec:
      selector:
        app: php
        tier: backend
      ports:
    protocol: TCP
    port: 9000
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. Protocol and port should be items from the `spec.ports` field.
It should look something like [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service)