# Kubernetes spec.ports required value error

Tags: kubernetes

I am running minikube version v1.15.1 on Windows 10 Home.

I started minikube using VirtualBox.

Below is my yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: web
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

I am running the command `kubectl apply -f filename.yaml` for creating the service. Getting error `The Service "my-service" is invalid: spec.ports: Required value`

I referred documentation and can see that the syntax is correct. Other places i referred were

i. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8619 which is having an issue opened for the same. It is closed and requested to follow up on stackoverflow.

ii. [The Service "php" is invalid: spec.ports: Required value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304332/the-service-php-is-invalid-spec-ports-required-value) this thread didn't help me as OP had a syntax error in the file.

Any suggestions would be helpful. I just started learning Kubernetes and it's my first attempt.

Comment: I think the manifest is good enough(tested, and almost identical files are in the official docs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service).

How about trying again or making sure you use the same manifest file as mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for that. i indeed checked that page. I was wondering if i am using wrong version of minikube or virtual box something like that. so thought someone would correct me on that.

Comment: What is your `kubectl version` ? Maybe you are using some old kubectl binary? Btw, The mentioned issues on github are very very old so it should not be a problem if your latest kubectl client version matched server version.

Comment: Both client and server version are 1.19.

Comment: @Yoonian thanks. actually the same config worked. I have copied a sample and edited according to my need and it worked. I have deleted the files which didn't work and recreated one from copied content.